# How to connect a specific Wi-Fi network in Android 9 (api 28) programmatically

Tags: java, android, wifi, android-wifi

I want to connect  a specific Wi-Fi network in Android 9 (api 28) programmatically.
I tried below code to connect.

```
 public boolean ConnectToNetworkWPA(String networkSSID, String password) {
                    try {
                        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) 
                        this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                        boolean b = wifiManager.isWifiEnabled();
                        if (!b) {
                            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                        } 
                        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
                        conf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";   // Please note the quotes. String should contain SSID in quotes
            
                        conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + password + "\"";
                        conf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
                        conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
                        conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
                        conf.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
                        conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
                        conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
                        conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
                        conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
                        conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP104);
                        conf.priority = 40;
            
                        Log.d("connecting", conf.SSID + " " + conf.preSharedKey);
            
                        int netid=wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
            
                        Log.d("after connecting", conf.SSID + " " + conf.preSharedKey);
            
                        List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
                        for( WifiConfiguration i : list ) {
                              if(i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + networkSSID + "\"")) {
                                wifiManager.disconnect();
                                wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
                                wifiManager.reconnect();
                                Log.d("re connecting", i.SSID + " " + conf.preSharedKey);
            
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        //WiFi Connection success, return true
                        return true;
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ex.getStackTrace()));
                        return false;
                    }
                }
```

I tried this code in android 7 it is working but not working in android 9. By the android docs, these methods still work with  API level 28.

Thanks for any ideas and help